# How to understand and solve crash report: SIGSEGV, SEGV_ACCERR

Tags: ios, crash-reports, segmentation-fault

I am getting sometimes this crash report:

```
Name: SIGSEGV
Reason: SEGV_ACCERR
Stack Trace:

0 MyApp 0x00070456 0x1000 + 455766
1 MyApp 0x0007a34d 0x1000 + 496461
2 MyApp 0x0007a4f1 0x1000 + 496881
3 MyApp 0x000d31dd 0x1000 + 860637
4 MyApp 0x00067f0f 0x1000 + 421647
5 MyApp 0x0005ad69 0x1000 + 367977
6 MyApp 0x000081e3 0x1000 + 29155
7 MyApp 0x00008ae9 0x1000 + 31465
8 CoreFoundation 0x35a547e4 __invoking___ + 68
9 CoreFoundation 0x359af7b1 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 160
10 Foundation 0x3556268f -[NSInvocationOperation main] + 114
11 Foundation 0x354fb393 -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 862
12 Foundation 0x35564793 __block_global_6 + 102
13 libdispatch.dylib 0x348dec59 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
14 libdispatch.dylib 0x348e1817 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 258
15 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32e0edfb _pthread_wqthread + 294
```

I don't understand this crash report. Also I don't know when this is happening.

Is there a way to find out more about this crash?

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report, which will convert the addresses in line 0 to 7 into meaningfull classes, methods and line numbers. Usually Xcode does that automatically if you still have the binary of the build that caused the crash around. Did you try to import the report into the Xcode organizer to get it symbolicated? How did you get this report?

Comment: @Kerni i am getting the crash report from crittercism.com. iam using the crittercism SDK for iOS. i see, that the app crashes on some devices and getting the log in my post. i can download the report, but it is a textfile. when i drag and drop that to xcode, it opens the textfile. what should i do?

Comment: @Kerni thank you for your answer. i have symbolicated it and now i have the point where it crashes. please write it as answer so i can mark it as answered.

Comment: I think crittercism has a symbolication feature, where you can upload the dSYM and they will symbolicate it. Not sure though, I am using my own hosted service :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to symbolicate the crash report, which will convert the addresses in line 0 to 7 into meaningfull classes, methods and line numbers. Usually Xcode does that automatically if you still have the binary of the build that caused the crash around.

Answer (score 2):

Question is old but there is better way then John Smith answer.

Currently the best approach is run using profiler (in XCode: Product/Profile) using respective template.
Most probably you need to use "Zombies" template which is now also supported on device :) not only on emulator.
When using this tool you have grater chance for spotting incorrect use of memory.

Answer (score 0):

The SIGSEV error is a signal send when you try to get memory that you are not allowed to touch

The best way to solve this problem is to put a breakpoint and jump line per line in order to find the line which is the problem

Or you can also put some Debug Logs to see were is the problem

For understand what SIGSEV or SEGV_ACCERR mean, you can search on internet more informations ;)

Comment: My search on the internet led me here :(

Comment: I searched for SIGSEV too and it brought me here. Rather than telling us to search the internet you don't you give a summary?

Comment: I searched on internet and got this https://books.google.co.in/books?id=4ld5AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA306&lpg=PA306&dq=sigsegv+error+ios&source=bl&ots=7mzKOxNHS_&sig=OrdZVkQ0dT68qsOqQghHyyT78bk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPgaaLorvVAhUUUI8KHY7IDaMQ6AEITzAG#v=onepage&q=sigsegv%20error%20ios&f=false